# String parsing and find common white space location

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am trying to parse a string and find a common white space location.

Here is my strings

```
abc   xyz 123   456
cba 1234a 45623 say
avc  4567 bv    456
```

There can any number of strings. I need a generic alogorithm preferable in c# where I can find out the common white space locations in above strings.

For example, in above strings common locations are

```
4, 10 ,16
```

which has white space in every string.

Approaches I have been trying includes Intersect , and to get all possible spaces and then compare to find out the common ones but I am trying to find out the optimal solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var stringList = new[] { "abc   xyz 123   456", "cba 1234a 45623 say", "avc  4567 bv    456" };
var shortest = stringList.OrderBy(s => s.Length).First();
var result = new Collection<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < shortest.Length; i++)
{
    if (stringList.All(c => c[i] == ' ')) result.Add(i+1);
}

// Test the results
foreach (var index in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(index);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a set of positions that are whitespace in the first string. Check those locations in the second sting, and remove the position from the set if the character at that position in the second string isn't whitespace. Repeat for the remaining strings.

Another possibility would be to finding the set of positions that are whitespace in each string, then find the intersection of those sets. This would have one potential advantage. While this will generally do more total work, part of that work (finding the individual sets) is easy to execute in parallel. I doubt this will win very often though (unless, perhaps, you have a lot of strings and a lot of cores). Though it may be less obvious, you can also find the set intersections in parallel as well -- you basically do a binary tree of intersections, so in the first iteration you find intersections between pairs, in the second you find intersections between pairs of results from the first iteration, and so on 'till you only have one set left. Assuming at least a many cores as strings, this reduces the time complexity from O(N) to O(log N).